# ¿Como cambiar el color de un item RecyclerView.ViewHolder utilizando ActionMode?

Tags: android, recyclerview

Intento marcar un ítem de un `RecyclerView`, después de un `setOnLongClickListener` el mismo cambia de color al que deseo, y se activa mi `ActionMode` normalmente con el ítem del color deseado, cuando salgo del `ActionMode` el ítem queda del mismo color y no regresa a su estado original, he intentado setear el color que tenia por defecto, pero no hace el cambio, también lo he intentado desde el método `onDestroyActionMode` y me manda el mensaje de "`La aplicación se ha detenido`", no se si es por que lo estoy haciendo mal o no esta permitido cambiar el color de un `layout` desde ese `método`, acá mi código:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder listViewHolder, final int i) {
        switch (getItemViewType(i)){
            case ITEM1:{
                OperatorListView operatorListView = (OperatorListView) items.get(i);
                ((ListViewHolder) listViewHolder).nameOp.setText(operatorListView.getName());
                ((ListViewHolder) listViewHolder).chargeOp.setText(operatorListView.getCharge());
                ((ListViewHolder) listViewHolder).imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent (activity, ViewOperatorActivity.class);
                        activity.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
                ((ListViewHolder) listViewHolder).imageView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                        if(actmode!=null){
                            return false;
                        }
                        ((ListViewHolder) listViewHolder).frameOperator.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                        actmode = ((AppCompatActivity) activity).startSupportActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            } break;
```

y aquí el `ActionMode.Callback`:

```
private ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback = new ActionMode.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
            actionMode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contextual_menu_operator, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                case R.id.edit:{
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "edittouch", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }
                case R.id.delete:{
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "deletetouch", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {
            actmode = null;
        }
    };
```

Y el `ListViewHolder`:

```
public class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private ImageView imageView;
        private TextView nameOp;
        private TextView chargeOp;
        private FrameLayout frameOperator;

        public ListViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ImageTouch);
            nameOp = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.NameOperator);
            chargeOp = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.OperatorCharge);
            frameOperator = (FrameLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.frame_list_view_operator);
        }
    }
```

Estas son las formas que he intentado, en el `onLongClickListener` antes de usar `actmode` probé esto:

```
if(i%2==0){
   ((ListViewHolder) listViewHolder).frameOperator.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
 } else {
   ((ListViewHolder) listViewHolder).frameOperator.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                }
```

y no regresa al color inicial de ninguna forma, variando algunas cosas en el condicional tampoco lo hace, ahora en el `onDestroyActionMode` intente esto:

```
ListViewHolder listviewholder = new ListViewHolder(view);
            lisviewholder.frameOperator.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```

y esto:

```
actionMode.getCustomView().setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```

y me manda el mensaje, "La aplicación se ha detenido"

Comment: Puedes mostrar como has tratado de settear el color del item y mostrar el error que produce.

Comment: Instanciando el ListViewHolder para obtener el Frame de allí en el `onDestroyActionMode`, algo similar a esto `((ListViewHolder) listViewHolder).frameOperator.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));`  pero haciendo esto `ListViewHolder listviewholder = new ListViewHolder(paso una vista vacía para que me permita intentar así)` pero me da error al momento que termina el `ActionMode` . también con un condicional en el `OnLongClickListener` en caso de que no se obtenga la posición lo deje del color inicial pero se cambia de igual forma y se queda negro. @DavidMinaya

Comment: Puedes actualizar tu respuesta con el código del comentario.

Comment: @DavidMinaya ya edite la pregunta y agregue los intentos y en donde los he implementado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tienes que entender que cada item esta representado por un ViewHolder, por lo que para volver a cambiar el color de un item tienes que volver a hacer referencia a ese mismo item.

Para hacerlo puedes almacenar la referencia de ese item en una variable global y después utilizar esa variable para cambiar el color del item en el ActionMode.

Primero almacenas una referencia del ViewHolder.

```
private ListViewHolder mListViewHolder; // Variable global

public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder listViewHolder, final int i) {
        switch (getItemViewType(i)){
            case ITEM1:{
                OperatorListView operatorListView = (OperatorListView) items.get(i);
                ((ListViewHolder) listViewHolder).nameOp.setText(operatorListView.getName());
                ((ListViewHolder) listViewHolder).chargeOp.setText(operatorListView.getCharge());
                ((ListViewHolder) listViewHolder).imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent (activity, ViewOperatorActivity.class);
                        activity.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
                ((ListViewHolder) listViewHolder).imageView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                        if(actmode!=null){
                            return false;
                        }

                        // Almacenas la referencia del ViewHolder
                        mListViewHolder = (ListViewHolder) listViewHolder;

                        mListViewHolder.frameOperator.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                        actmode = ((AppCompatActivity) activity).startSupportActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            } break;
```

Después vuelves a cambiar el color del item.

```
private ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback = new ActionMode.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
            actionMode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contextual_menu_operator, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                case R.id.edit:{
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "edittouch", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }
                case R.id.delete:{
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "deletetouch", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {

            // Vuelve a cambiar el color del item
            mListViewHolder.frameOperator.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));

            actmode = null;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Prueba y me dices si te dio resultado.

Comment: Perfecto, funcionó, algo sencillo que me tenia pensando de mas, gracias!, siempre se aprende algo nuevo :) .

Comment: Es un problema común. Recuerda que en la programación orientada a objetos casi todo se maneja por referencias y que no tienes que hacer todo en un solo lugar. Si tienes que modificar algo en el futuro o en otro lugar, siempre recuerda almacenar una referencia.

Comment: excelente consejo, lo tendré en cuenta!